# Proxy stdout/stderr keeping order in bash

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

I am trying to add some information in front of every line output from a file, by:

- catching both stdout and stderr
- prepending the information
- outputting to the original handle

Here is my test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Test proxying stdout and stderr
#

function proxy-stdouterr() {
    local name="$1"
    local handle=$2
    while IFS='' read -r line
    do
        echo -e "[ ${name}: ${line} ]" >&${handle}
    done
}

# Output some messages and attempt to parse them
(
    echo "1: Normal message"
    echo "2: Error" >&2
    echo "3: Normal message"
    echo "4: Error" >&2
) 2> >(proxy-stdouterr "stderr" 2) > >(proxy-stdouterr "stdout" 1)
```

This works fairly well but doesn't preserve the order in the terminal (Ubuntu 12.04).

When not proxying outputs:

```
1: Normal message
2: Error
3: Normal message
4: Error
```

However when proxying the order isn't kept. Worse this is not deterministic, most of the time it is:

```
[ stderr: 2: Error ]
[ stderr: 4: Error ]
[ stdout: 1: Normal message ]
[ stdout: 3: Normal message ]
```

But occasionally:

```
[ stderr: 2: Error ]
[ stdout: 1: Normal message ]
[ stderr: 4: Error ]
[ stdout: 3: Normal message ]
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is a basic synchronization problem: when you have to producers writing to a shared resource in parallel, you can't guarantee the order in which those writes occur without some form of coordination.

Comment: Also, +1 for providing an example that clearly demonstrates the question!

Comment: larsks is correct.  The output is being split into two separate IO streams: STDOUT and STDERR (the "producers"), which then get "proxied", prefixed, and then echoed back to the console.  The time to process each stream can vary, especially with a bash function as part of the stream, so there's no way to synchronize their output (without using some kind of signal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others noted, this is a synchronization problem with no obvious
answer without knowing more about which parts you specifically control
and want to change.

There are IMHO two main surfaces of attack:

- stream buffering.  Most C-derived programs do not buffer stderr,
  buffer stdin and stdout by line if they're a terminal and buffer
  them fully otherwise.  This explains why stderr tends to always come
  up first in your example.  A cheap cop-out is to use `/usr/bin/echo`
  instead of builtin `echo`, so you'll get a flushed stream at the end
  of every line (and a lot of delay for process spawning).  It solves
  your example 100% for what I've tried, so it could be enough for you
  too.  If you've got control on the command that generates the lines,
  ensure both stdout and stderr are line-buffered.
- process scheduling.  You've got two processes competing to read from
  both streams.  Should there be data flowing on both at the time,
  they're in a race against each other.  You can mitigate that by
  having a single process do that, but I'm not sure it's possible to
  keep it efficient in native `bash` (no programmable POSIX `select`
  available to the end-user)

In any case, if there's queueing anywhere in the picture, you're
screwed as far as keeping the order goes.